# How is my ranking determined?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

So... I'm pretty confused. Halo 5 has monthly ladders that reset, with different rankings for each game mode. I get that. Your ranking is calculated after you play 10 games in a specific playlist for each month, and continually updated after that. That's pretty normal.

My question deals with how exactly these ranks are determined... It seems to be supremely inconsistent. I've had times where I won almost all of my first 10 games while performing well... only to end up in Gold. Other times, I've lost many of my games and done not so great and ended up in Onyx (the best league). Ranking updates after each match seem similarly confusing. What factors go into determining my matchmaking ranking?

Comment: I know after your rank is determined, only win/loss affects it, but as for the first 10. there is some metrics like KDA and accuracy and such taken into account that 343i hasn't given the hard numbers for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranking in halo 5 is not like most other games. The better you do in games, the higher your rank gets. Your CSR or "Competitive Score Rating" is what determines the rank. When you don't do well in a game, your CSR goes down, but it won't ever put you back a rank.

[Here's a interesting link with more information](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/news/enter-the-arena)